# I cannot figure out what causes layout constraint warnings in my message bubble cell

Tags: ios, swift, constraints

I've been trying to solve this problem for a few days now and I haven't been able to understand what is wrong with my constraints, and warnings keep popping up in the console.
Here are my UI elements:

```
let messageText : UILabel = {
    let label = UILabel()
    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    label.numberOfLines = 0
    label.backgroundColor = .clear
    label.clipsToBounds = false
    label.font = UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17)
    return label
}()

private let messageCard : UIView = {
    let card = UIView()
    card.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    card.layer.cornerRadius = 16
    card.layer.masksToBounds = true
    card.clipsToBounds = false
    return card
}()

private let avatar : CachedImageView = {
    var imageView = CachedImageView()
    imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15).isActive = true
    imageView.isAvatar = true
    return imageView
}()

private let stackView : UIStackView = {
    let stView = UIStackView()
    stView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    stView.backgroundColor = .clear
    stView.axis = .vertical
    return stView
}()
```

Here is my initialiser for the cell:

```
override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

    self.clipsToBounds = false

    stackView.addArrangedSubview(messageText)
    stackView.addArrangedSubview(avatar)
    addSubview(messageCard)
    addSubview(stackView)

    let constraints = [
        stackView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: bubbleMargin + bubblePadding),
        stackView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -(bubbleMargin + bubblePadding)),
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualToConstant: 300),
        stackView.widthAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 30),
        //stackView.heightAnchor.constraint(greaterThanOrEqualToConstant: 10), // ну хз

        messageCard.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.topAnchor, constant: -bubblePadding),
        messageCard.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.bottomAnchor, constant: bubblePadding),
        messageCard.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: -bubblePadding),
        messageCard.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: bubblePadding),

        /*messageText.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: 20),
        messageText.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: -20),*/

        /*avatar.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),
        avatar.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 15),
        avatar.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.centerXAnchor),
        avatar.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.centerYAnchor),*/
    ]

    leftConstr = stackView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: bubbleMargin + bubblePadding)
    rightConstr = stackView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -(bubbleMargin + bubblePadding))

    leftConstr.isActive = true

    for c in constraints {
        c.isActive = true
    }
}
```

Here is the method that fills the message bubble:

```
func setMessage() {
    messageText.text = messageWrapper.message.text
    messageText.textColor = .white
    messageCard.backgroundColor = messageWrapper.message.out == 1 ? .darkGray : .lightGray
    leftConstr.isActive = messageWrapper.message.out == 0
    rightConstr.isActive = messageWrapper.message.out == 1
    avatar.isHidden = messageWrapper.message.out == 1
    if messageWrapper.message.out == 0 {
        if let photo = messageWrapper.group?.photo50 {
            avatar.setSource(url: photo)
        }
        if let photo = messageWrapper.profile?.photo100 {
            avatar.setSource(url: photo)
        }
    }
}
```

I've also noticed that the warnings really only appear when I start scrolling, but the warning suggests that there is something wrong with a constraints that the setMessage() method doesn't ever touch.

[screenshot of the warning, since stack overflow really wasn't having it as a code snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USD7C.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, IvanM! You can try pasting your constraint warning into https://www.wtfautolayout.com for a more visual explanation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your stack view with needs to be <= 300 points, but the stack view width must be equal to message cell width - 13 - 13. Since your message cell width is 414, and 414 - 13 - 13 = 388, and 388 is not <= 300, you get the error.

You should either remove the stack view's width constraint, or change either the leading or trailing constraint to be more flexible.

There are many solutions. For example, you could remove these two lines:

```
messageCard.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.leadingAnchor, constant: -bubblePadding),
messageCard.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: stackView.trailingAnchor, constant: bubblePadding),
```

and instead center the stack view within `messageCard`.

But ultimately you need to not give it conflicting constraints.

Comment: I see. This is strange though, as visually it looks just as intended. The message bubble never seems to be wider than what I set it to be

Comment: Also, I never use both of these constraints at the same time. I use them to clip the message to the left or to the right depending on whether it is outbox or inbox.

Comment: *I never use both of these constraints at the same time*. Yes you do. Both constraints are active after the init method is called, but before `setMessage()` is called.

Comment: Wait, but isn't it the rightConstraint and leftConstraint that are causing the problem? I don't think it has to do with the 2 lines you specified, because I tried commenting out rightConstraint and leftConstraint and that resulted in the warnings disappearing. (but of course also in the fact that messages didn't clip to left and right)